# Generate a fully readable Render Tree from html with webkit?

Tags: html, css, dom, webkit, render

I am starting a new project of my own which mainly consists in creating a simple 3D web browser (With some other extra stuff that is out of topic here). I already have the tools for the 3d front-end, they´re going to be in C# with Unity.

I´ve educated myself on the current web browsers parsing/rendering process, and came to the conclusion that I shouldn´t re-implement the whole html/css parsing.

So, what I need is an approach that can get me a readable rendering tree from an html/url, where I can fetch an element and it´s list of all processed style attributes, just before rendering.

Webkit seems like the job for this, I see it has RenderObject and related classes that create a tree, but I´m still in the process of building / integrating with Visual Studio.

Has someone done something similar that can point me to the classes or project I need to derive from?

I´ve also studied other managed-code open source projects:

[CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/) : Written in java, handles basic sites very well but still misses some CSS Styling, does not have JS engine.

[HTMLRenderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) : Written in C#, only tested with sample pages, not from online websites yet. Also misses JS engine and all of the robustness from webkit.